# Questions regarding the distinction between XeTeX and XeLaTeX and how they relate to TeX and LaTeX?

Tags: xetex

Briefest possible version of the question (after having seen comments):

Is the only distinction between XeTeX and XeLaTeX that the commands `xetex` and `xelatex` are differently compatible with *TeX* and *LaTeX* formatted documents?

That is, the *XeTeX* and *XeLaTeX* typesetting engines are actually the same, and that both `xetex` and `xelatex` are commands that are part of these engines, and those commands differ.

---

What are the main differences between `XeTeX` and `XeLaTeX`? Are they just the analogous differences between `TeX` and `LaTeX`, where the former is a typesetting engine along a basic set of macros(`plain-tex`) and the latter is a more comprehensive set of macros?

Does `XeTeX` contain `LaTeX` macros? On the [`XeTeX` webpage](http://xetex.sourceforge.net/), it seems to suggest this, saying

> `XeTeX` is now part of the standard `TeX` distribution *TeX Live* and works well with `TeX` macro packages like `LaTeX` and `ConTeXt`.

If so, do they need to be specially invoked when using `XeTeX` to process your document?

Additionally, if `LaTeX` is already "included" in some sense in `XeTeX`, then what is different in `XeLaTeX`? I.e., are `XeTeX` and `XeLaTeX` identical?

Are the maintainers `XeTeX` the same as the maintainers of `XeLaTeX`? If so where can one find information about this (note it is not included in either the  [TUG linked reference on XeTeX](http://ctan.org/pkg/xetexref) nor the [`XeTeX` webpage](http://xetex.sourceforge.net/))?

Are there any packages that are supported by `XeTeX` that are not supported by `XeLaTeX`? Are those the same packages that are supported by `TeX` but not `LaTeX`?

Are there any packages that are supported by `XeLaTeX` that are not supported by `LaTeX`? Are those the same packages that are supported by `LaTeX` but not `TeX`?

Is `XeTeX` structured such that updates to the `TeX` or `LaTeX` codebases are automatically incorporated?

Is `XeLaTeX` structured such that updates to `TeX` or `LaTeX` codebases are automatically incorporated?

---

As anticipated this was flagged with being a duplicate, it includes many other aspects than previous questions had(e.g., asking about the maintainers of *XeLaTeX*), and I made prefatory remarks about how it is different. If you think this is a duplicate, please read below.

A similar question has actually been [asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78302/whats-the-difference-between-xelatex-and-xetex), but it was listed as a duplicate with a pointer to a question that does not actually answer the original question regarding the difference between `XeTeX` and `XeLaTeX`. [I am new to TeX. Should I use LaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42628/i-am-new-to-tex-should-i-use-latex-xelatex) answers a question about which typesetting engine would be most useful to begin with as a new user. The distinction between `XeTeX` and `XeLaTeX` is not written anywhere; in fact, `XeTeX` and `XeLaTeX` do not even appear in the same sentence or even in the same paragraph.

An answer that would seem to almost hold exists in a different question ([XeTeX and XeLaTeX in TeXworks editor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35065/xetex-and-xelatex-in-texworks-editor)), but it actually seems to not be accurate, as it claims XeTeX cannot be used when writing in the `LaTeX` format. It may be the options in the TeXworks actually follow this convention, even though the `xetex` command when run on the command line would itself be capable of processing `LaTeX` formatted documents.

I have looked for a long time today trying to find an answer to this, which I would then have just written up as a blog post, but I can't find anything definitive.

Before flagging this as a duplicate, please consider the following:

- It is not obvious that `XeTeX` and `XeLaTeX` bear a relationship like `TeX` and `LaTeX` to one another, even if that is the case. For example, `BibTeX` and `BibLaTeX` also share this naming convention, but the difference between them is not the same as the difference between `TeX` and `LaTeX`.
- If you look in many questions and answers about `XeTeX` or `XeLaTeX`, the two terms are used as if they can be exchanged freely (which surely is not the case with `TeX` and `LaTeX`). Indeed, the question author in [XeTeX and XeLaTeX in TeXworks editor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35065/xetex-and-xelatex-in-texworks-editor) states this assumption explicitly.
- The webpage for `XeTeX` says nothing about the relation between `XeTeX` and `XeLaTeX`, much of the documentation about `XeTeX` only obliquely mentions `xelatex` the command if it mentions `XeLaTeX` at all, and `XeLaTeX` does not seem to have a webpage of its own.
- I'm guessing this is searched often enough that having the answer tied to a question that matches people's expected search terms will be useful for many. Even if questions about `TeXWorks` and "which engine should a new user use" answered this (and as noted above, they don't) they will not be what people search to find this answer.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate I'll find something but the relationship between tex and latex is the same as the relationship between xetex and xelatex,  tex, pdftex, xetex, luatex, are all tex-like engines and the same latex sources may be used with them to produce laetx, pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex respectively

Comment: Well, `XeTeX` is `TeX` with OpenType/`.ttf` support etc., whereas `XeLaTeX` uses the LaTeX format variant of `XeTeX`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you were to try to process a `LaTeX` formatted document using `TeX`, it would not work. If you were to process a `LaTeX` formatted document using `XeTeX`, it would work. So it cannot be exactly the same relationship. I point this out in my comments at the bottom regarding whether this is a duplicate.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `XeTeX` is also compatible with `LaTeX` formatted documents, so that cannot be the distinction between them.

Comment: The relationship is exactly the same as the latex source code (which is written in tex) is the same in both cases (apart from a very few minor differences) do not confuse tex-the-program with the plain tex format.

Comment: @Mico I have looked through there, and nowhere does it answer all of the questions that I raise, and in particular it does not actually address the distinction between `XeTeX` and `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: the command `xetex` will run xetex with the plain tex format which will fail with latex documents in _exactly_ the same way as plain tex with classical tex does,

Comment: @mpacer: I doubt that the `xetex` binary will compile a latex document.

Comment: Eight questions in one!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So am I to understand that this is a distinction between the `XeTeX` typesetting engine and the `xetex` command, or is it that the documentation is incorrect when it says that it is compatible with `LaTeX` macros?

Comment: @mpacer - This site works best if a posting raises exactly one main question or issue. Your posting raises a whole bunch of (not-all-that-clearly-structures) questions. The three links I provided in my earlier comment should address virtually all of your questions. However, I will agree that there's probably not one single posting out there that answers all of your questions in the exact same order as you've posed them.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That may be the case, but that is the command `xetex`, not the typesetting engine `XeTeX`, which is claimed to have that compatibility. So this suggests that there may be no difference between `XeTeX` and `XeLaTeX` but that there is a difference between `xetex` and `xelatex`? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @Mico I do not mind if the questions are not answered in the order that I posted them. What I do mind is that nowhere is the actual distinction between these two systems laid out. What I'm now gathering is that there are two distinctions to be made, one between `xetex` and `xelatex` the commands  and between *XeTeX* and *XeLaTeX* the typesetting engines. While there may be a difference between the former, there may not be the latter. Also, no where is the information posted about who maintains XeLaTeX or `xelatex`.

Comment: Off-topic: People may mind here that there are answers to your other questions but you did not accept them (No, I am not one of the users who answered one of them) ;-)

Comment: On the xetex website they say xetex is compatible with LaTeX and not that it includes LaTeX.  That only means that the LaTeX macro package can be load in xetex.  xelatex is just xetex with LaTeX already loaded.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer off-topic: Thank you for the heads up — it had been a while since I'd posted that and I had had difficulty deciding which of the answers to accept as the top two answers were both great. I picked one, and will try to avoid allowing that to happen in the future.

Comment: You may be interested in [this terminology article](http://seanallred.com/tex/2015/05/25/tex-terminology.html).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### `tex`

`tex` is an executable file--a runnable program. By default it has the Plain TeX format preloaded, so when you run `tex file.tex` it is prepared to read macros defined in `plain.tex`. It produces DVI output.

### `pdftex`

`pdftex` is another version of the `tex` executable that includes certain extensions to the original program (the `e-tex` extensions, including additional memory registers). By default this produces PDF output directly instead of DVI. It also has the Plain TeX format preloaded.

---

### `latex`

The command `latex` calls the `pdftex` program (or "engine") but with the LaTeX format preloaded instead of Plain TeX, and set to produce DVI output.

### `pdflatex`

The command `pdflatex` calls the `pdftex` engine but with the LaTeX format preloaded instead of Plain TeX, and set to produce PDF output.

---

### `xetex`

`xetex` is a different executable file from `tex` and `pdftex`. It includes extensions to the original program to allow Unicode input and right-to-left typesetting, among other features. By default it has the Plain TeX format preloaded and produces PDF output.

### `xelatex`

The command `xelatex` calls the `xetex` engine but with the LaTeX format preloaded instead of Plain TeX and produces PDF output.

---

### `luatex`

`luatex` is yet another distinct executable file, a partial reimplementation of `tex` that incorporates the `lua` scripting language. Like `xetex`, `luatex` is built to accept Unicode input. It has the Plain TeX format preloaded and produces PDF output.

### `lualatex`

The command `lualatex` calls the `luatex` engine with the LaTeX format preloaded instead of Plain TeX, and produces PDF output.

---

### Examples

*Plain TeX format*

You can successfully compile this Plain Tex file with either `tex`, `pdftex`, `xetex`, or `luatex`:

```
Test of Plain \TeX.\bye
```

*Plain TeX format with Unicode input*

If you use Unicode characters, you will only be able to print those characters by running `xetex` or `luatex` *and* selecting a font that includes them:

```
\font\tenrm=ecrm1000 \rm
Test of Unicode with Plain \TeX: Matthäuspassion, esdrújulo.\bye
```

*LaTeX format*

To compile a LaTeX document, use `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test of \LaTeX.
\end{document}
```

*LaTeX format with Unicode input*

If you use Unicode characters, you can print them in two ways:

1. use `pdflatex` and set the proper input and font encoding using
   `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages, or
2. use `xelatex` or
   `lualatex` and select a Unicode font using the `fontspec` package.

For `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Test of Unicode with \LaTeX: Matthäuspassion, esdrújulo.
\end{document}
```

For `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
 \begin{document}
 Test of Unicode with \LaTeX: Matthäuspassion, esdrújulo.
 \end{document}
```

Comment: there's also "etex" which contains the extensions to registers.  (it seems to be included in tex live.)  pdftex adds the pdf output.

Comment: This is much better than my attempt at answering. The only thing that I think would make it better is a further clarification about the meanings of the terms when discussing XeTeX and XeLaTeX, where they are often interchanged without anyone mentioning the distinctions between format files and typesetting engines. This interchanging probably doesn't happen with the commands `xetex` and `xelatex` because that kind of ambiguity isn't possible on the command line.

Comment: @mpacer There is really only one program, `xetex`. The program checks the command with which it was called (in the C programming language, this would be `argv[0]`), and if it is `xetex` it uses Plain, and if it is `xelatex` it uses LaTeX. There is no "XeLaTeX" format, just LaTeX format.

Comment: @AndrewCashner Is that why `xetex --ini latex.ltx` is sufficient to generate the non-existing "XeLaTeX" format file `xelatex.ini`?

Comment: @mpacer There actually is a `xelatex.ini`, I see: it executes  a few commands and then ends with `\input latex.ltx`. So I suppose there is technically a XeLaTeX format. I should have said language instead of format. XeLaTeX documents are just LaTeX documents, is what I meant.

Comment: You can also compile accented characters without XeTeX, TeX is capable of it if you use the same encoding for font and file. In your example you used the font `ecrm1000`, it would be able to compile if you save the file with Latin 1 encoding.

Comment: This is a great answer that clarifies a lot of very similar but confusing concepts to a TeX newbie like me.

Comment: Just for agonizing correctness, XeTeX and PDFtex are themselves based on/incorporate eTeX, and thus contain the extended registers that eTeX introduced.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this is a complete answer, but based on the comments on this question so far, some parts of the answer are starting to form.

Because the question asks about XeTeX and XeLaTeX specifically, I will address it specifically, but as suggested by the chosen answer and pointed out in the comments, there is nothing special about the relationship between XeTeX and XeLaTeX. However, because of this specificity it is possible to go into greater detail though it will not generalize without modification to the other cases(at least in terms of the exact characters typed in commands).

There are two sets of things being conflated here: *XeTeX* is a typesetting engine, *XeLaTeX* is a format file for compiling *LaTeX* formatted documents with the *XeTeX* engine, the `xetex` command line command is the binary that actually does the compiling, and `xelatex` is a convenience wrapper function for including the appropriate format files to the `xetex` command.

If you speak of *XeTeX* and *XeLaTeX* as both being typesetting engines, then there is no difference between the two (or you are mistaken in describing *XeLaTeX* as a typesetting engine).

However, the `xetex` and `xelatex` commands are not the same. In fact, `xelatex` is a convenience wrapper for the `xetex` command with particular arguments.

`xetex` will not be able to compile a document using the instruction codes specified by the *LaTeX* format file, it expects a plain-tex formatted document just as the `tex` binary does.
`xelatex` is a wrapper that is essentially the same as `xetex "&xelatex"` which is able to process *LaTeX* formatted documents, which involves invoking `xelatex.ini` as part of the preamble.

This answer helped a good deal for clarifying this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126634/67313

You may be able to generate the necessary format file by using `xetex --ini latex.ltx`, see [How to build xelatex from xetex source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58739/how-to-build-xelatex-from-xetex-source#comment123988_58739), though it seems that additional code may need to be added to build something actually equivalent to the `xelatex.ini` format file.

Thank you also to everyone in the comments for helping clarify points in which I was "off" in my understanding and description.

Comment: This answer shows that you haven't understood what xetex and xelatex are, according to me.

Comment: You're making this much more complicated than it is. TeX is to LaTeX what pdfTeX is to pdfLaTeX, XeTeX is to XeLaTeX, and LuaTeX is to LuaLaTeX. An "engine" is a binary and understands a set of primitive instructions to perform the actual typesetting. A "format" is a group of macros (not a "binary") meant to make the primitives usable by humans. TeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX use the "Plain (e)TeX" format with the respective engines, whereas LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX use the "LaTeX2e" format with the respective engines. (LaTeX2e superseded LaTeX2.09 in the mid-1990s.)

Comment: @Mico -- actually "tex" remains without the addition of e-tex; it is the original "knuth tex".  at leasf on the system i'm working on, the command "etex" brings up the extended version, based on pdftex.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Sorry, I guess I was trying too hard to group TeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX. I should have separated "TeX" further into "Knuth tex" and "eTeX"...

Comment: @Mico -- oh, you're excused.  most people don't really need to know that, or care.

Comment: @Mico I think it's made more complicated by the fact that `xelatex` is a binary, but that binary happens to just be a wrapper for `xetex` with the appropriate format preloaded. So if you run `which xelatex` and look at the file that is specified by the return path, it is not readable (by humans). Only if you knew to look for `xelatex.ini` in the source would you be able to find the relevant human readable format file.

Comment: Maybe we're using different meanings for "binary". As I think I said: XeTeX uses the Plain-TeX format with the xetex engine, and XeLaTeX uses the LaTeX2e format with the xetex engine. I would *not*, repeat *not*, call XeLaTeX a "binary".

Comment: @Mico If you type `which xelatex` in your terminal, and then open the file on that path, is that file a binary file? For me that is the case, which I was saying is part of where the confusion begins… but maybe that shouldn't be a binary file and something is wrong with my setup?

Comment: With a Unix-based TeX distribution (sorry, I have no idea how things are done under MS Windows), the file called `xelatex` is a symbolic link to another file called `xetex`. That's why I would not call `xelatex` a "binary". The first thing `xetex` (the binary) does is to examine how it was called: If it was called as `xetex`, the Plain-TeX format is loaded; if it was called as `xelatex`, the LaTeX2e format is loaded.

Comment: I use OS X, hadn't though to check for a symbolic link. I don't entirely understand how – if it is just a symbolic link – it knows to load the correct format, since I had thought that symbolic links were literally pointers to to inode of the target, and thus that they couldn't be different from one another. But this is good to know, I'll have to learn more about how to do that with symbolic links, because I could see that being useful.

Comment: @mpacer Here's a C program that prints out the name with which it was called. 
`#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 printf("You called %s\n", argv[0]);
 return(0);
}`

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything and seems to imply that there is something special about the relationship between xetex and xelatex that is not shared between tex and latex or pdftex and pdflatex, which is simply not the case.

Comment: @mpacer If you compile that as executable file `one` and run it as `./one`, it will output "`You called ./one`". If you then create a symbolic link to it called `two`, running `./two` will produce the output "`You called ./two`".

Comment: "xetex ... It uses the tex binary as its underpinnings." is just wrong. the whole point is that xetex is _not_ tex but an alternative, although the latex macros work with either (and with luatex).

Comment: The term "formatted" in a sentence such as "`xetex` will not be able to compile a *LaTeX* formatted document" is severely misleading. There are no formatting guidelines for documents to be processed by any of the tex engines. There can be one or ten blank lines between paragraphs; one can have single or multiple spaces between every word; one can indent lines in an environment, or one can have every line start at the left-hand margin. The various formats (such as PlainTeX and LaTeX2e) understand different instruction sets. Please use a more appropriate term than "formatted".

Comment: @AndrewCashner Thank you for that code example and explanation. That helped a lot.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried to address your not special emphasis concerns and fix the error regarding TeX underpinnings. Thank you for pointing both out. Please let me know if it still seems problematic.

Comment: @Mico thank you for pointing out that distinction I attempted to remove the misleading part. Do the changes address your concern?