# Difference between command xetex and xelatex

Tags: xetex

What is the difference between the command `xetex` and `xelatex` in a `TeX Live 2020/Debian` installation?

AFAICS `xelatex` is a symbolic link to `xetex`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       5 17. Feb 2021  /usr/bin/xelatex -> xetex
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2723136 13. Mär 2021  /usr/bin/xetex
```

But when calling `xetex filename.tex` I get an undefined control sequence at `\documentclass`. Calling `xelatex filename.tex` works fine.

I see that they have different outputs:

- `xetex` outputs (preloaded format=xetex)
- `xelatex` outputs (preloaded format=xelatex)

**Note**: This is not a duplicate of [Questions regarding the distinction between XeTeX and XeLaTeX and how they relate to TeX and LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296616/questions-regarding-the-distinction-between-xetex-and-xelatex-and-how-they-relat). There the question was about the general differences in `xetex` and `xelatex`. Here I'm asking about why the symbolic link `xelatex` works different than its target `xetex`!

Comment: Xelatex loads the latex format which you need for documents starting with documentclass. xetex loads the plainyex format

Comment: The first thing the `xetex` executable does it to check how it was called. If it was called as "xetex", the program will next load the "PlainTeX" format (to be precise: the etex variant of the plainTeX format). If, OTOH; if it was called as "xelatex", the program will next load the "LaTeX" format.

Comment: Pdflatex and pdftex does the same, look at the program name it is called by and adjust it's output after it. This is quite normal